# MVC 4 Login and Policy on different DataBase

Tags: database, model-view-controller, authentication, policy, role

I'm trying to find a tutorial or help for solve this scenario.

In my MVC 4 application I want to have a Database where I store login information (username, password, connection strings ).
When User Login success, I want to open database with connection string stored in User Table, and get the policy from specific database (this database also contains the application data).
This means that a user can access to multiple database, and have different policy on every database.
Administrator can create a new user on Login Database, associate user with databases, and set policies for every Database.

Someone can help me or know a tutorial for doing that.
Thanks

Comment: Use different data context with different connection string of various databases.